# Multiply and sum values in a file

Tags: python, bash, perl, shell, awk

We have a file - `input.txt` - matrix of 5rows 9cols (real file is 10K+ rows and 40K+ cols):

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9
0.8 1   0.8 0.6 0.9 0.4 0.3 0.1 0.6
1   0.6 0.5 0.6 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.2
0.4 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.6 0.3 0.3
0.9 0.2 1   0.1 0.9 0.8 0.6 0.9 0.2
0.9 1   0.2 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.2
```

**Note 1:** files do not have headers - kept it here to reference.
**Note 2:** solution has to scale to real data with 40K+ columns.
**Note 3:** added python and perl tags, whichever performs better.

Need to convert it to below `output.txt` - matrix 5rows 3cols:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
2.6 1.7 1.3
1.6 0.5 0.9
0.7 2.4 0.9
2.2 2.5 1.3
1.4 1.9 0.7
```

Logic:

```
Output_Col1 = (Input_Col2) + (Input_Col3*2)
Output_Col2 = (Input_Col5) + (Input_Col6*2)
Output_Col3 = (Input_Col8) + (Input_Col9*2)
```

Effort, tried to make matrix files for column twos and threes as separate files, if only I could multiply the 2nd file by two then sum those two files... probably there is an easier way.

```
ncol=9
cut -d" " -f`seq -s "," 2 3 $ncol` input.txt > col2s.txt
cut -d" " -f`seq -s "," 3 3 $ncol` input.txt > col3s.txt
```

Comment: If your input file has >40,000 columns, the most basic issue that you're going to have is whether the tools you use can read in a line that big (i.e. one line likely to be around 160Kb) older tools may not be able to (some are limited to 4k per line) I'd suggest that you work first on breaking those down a bit before applying the multiplication.

Comment: How often do you need to process such a file? If you do it often, keep in mind that splitting columns will be most important bottleneck, and you can save time by only focusing on the columns you need, but that will need some custom programming: See my blog post [Splitting long lines is slow](http://www.nu42.com/2013/02/splitting-long-lines-is-slow.html).

Comment: I have about ~900 files, gzipped size vary 500MB to 3GB.

Comment: That sounds similar to the problem I had. You definitely want to keep the files gzipped, and use a routine similar to what I wrote to extract only the fields you want. Are the new columns to be added to existing columns, or do they replace specific columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk

```
awk '{print ($2+($3*2)),($5+($6*2)),($8+($9*2))}'
```

On the first record, prints the first three fields.
Then literally just prints out the equations you have asked for

Scalable version

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=3)x=(x?x FS:"")($i+($(i+1)*2));print x;x=y}' file
```

Output:

```
2.6 1.7 1.3
1.6 0.5 0.9
0.7 2.4 0.9
2.2 2.5 1.3
1.4 1.9 0.7
```

Comment: How would this scale to 40K+ columns?

Comment: @zx8754 Added scalable version

Comment: You can skip the NR==1 handling, as zx8754 wrote `Note: files do not have headers - kept it here to reference.`

Comment: @WalterA Cheers didn't see that !

Comment: @JID is awk not limited to 32767 number columns? I have 40000+ columns.

Comment: @zx8754 Gawk has no limit.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lane 'print join "\t", $F[1] + $F[2] * 2, $F[4] + $F[5] * 2, $F[7] + $F[8] * 2' input.txt > output.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-l` adds newline after each `print`
- `-a` splits each line into the `@F` array
- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each

If you have more neighbouring columns to process, you can use a shorter notation:

```
print join "\t", map $F[$_] + $F[$_ + 1] * 2, 1, 4, 7
```

(replace `1, 4, 7` with the actual list of the left columns).

Comment: How does this scale for 40K column file?

Comment: @zx8754: TITS - Try It To see.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I am not familiar with perl, could you explain the code more?

Comment: @zx8754: [print](http://p3rl.org/print), [join](http://p3rl.org/join), [map](http://p3rl.org/map).

Comment: Tried `perl -lane 'print join "\t", map $F[$_] + $F[$_ + 1] * 2, 2, 5, 8' input.txt`. 1row 1col value is `2`, it should be `2.6 = 1+0.8*2`.

Comment: @zx8754: Columns are numbered from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using bc and a loop:

(EDIT: Get rid of UUOC)

```
while read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c_others; do
        out1=$(echo $c2 + $c3 \* 2 | bc)
        out2=$(echo $c5 + $c6 \* 2 | bc)
        out3=$(echo $c8 + $c9 \* 2 | bc)
        echo ${out1} ${out2} ${out3}
done < input.txt
```

Result:

```
2.6 1.7 1.3
1.6 .5 .9
.7 2.4 .9
2.2 2.5 1.3
1.4 1.9 .7
```

When you want a 0 for floats < 1, you can parse the output:

```
| sed -e 's/ \./ 0./g' -e 's/^\./0./'
```

I am afraid the additional sed parsing will make this the slowest solution.

Comment: Thats gonna be realllllly slow for a 400 million record file.Also OP said there are 40k+ columns.

Comment: @JID I wrote it was slow indeed, added it for showing different techniques (when OP doesn't want to use perl/awk). 10K+ rows shouldn't be a problem. I do not know if preprocessing with `cut -f1-10` will help you or me.

Answer (score 0):

Given the size of your file, my preference would be to process it using a specific program in Python, Perl or even a compiled language such as C/C++. This is likely to be much faster than a shell script, and have better error handling.

Using the shell you might use something like:

```
# Outer loop deal with each line in the file.
cat my_file | while read line
do
    # Inner loop. Deal with each calculation on the line.
    while [[ ${line} ]]
    do
        echo ${line} | cut -d' ' -f1-3  | nawk '{printf("%d\t",$2+($3*2))}'
        line=$(echo ${line} | cut -s -d' ' -f4-)
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

Comment: Awk is faster than both perl and python.`read` is possibly one of the slowest methods you could use.

Comment: @JID completely agree on the slowness of `read` - my solution shows that it is possible, rather than sensible. Would have preferred an `awk` only solution but I'm not sure about the scalablility to 40K columns. Personally would probably use Python or C++ for this.

Comment: Should add that my experience of long line in `awk` is not good. Years (decades ago in fact) I had to do something similar and awk let me down badly with an undocumented 4K line limit. I had to scramble and find another solution quickly and since then I've been cautious about using it for long line applications, though I accept that `nawk` & `gawk` are likely not to be limited in this way. So, ultimately, mostly a personal thing.

Comment: Fair enough, but you are correct that there are no limits on Gawk, although I am unsure of the others.